# Debugging in eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

My development server is linux server.I access linux server in windows through putty..Recently i started using  eclipse CDT for c++ developmet.I add the projects to eclipse through network share(samba).I can also compile the program through eclipse by adding  linux server which gives me inbuily putty acesss(no need for me to again login to putty).My problem now is there any way i can do debugging in eclipse also???.Right now all my coding and compiling works are done in eclipse itself only thing missing is debugging.

Comment: eclipse CDT has a great debugger built in. just look for it.

Comment: ya i know that..but am using eclipse in windows ,editing the code which is there in linux server

Comment: Yes, and? You can only debug code that you run somewhere. If you compile your code for your current windows system, than it will run and be debuggable on your windows PC; if you want to run and debug it on that linux server, you will need to set up a cross compiler, and a way to deploy things on the server. There's lots of documentation on that.

Comment: i am compling for linux machine using rdt server access for eclipse..that is in eclipse in can connect to linux server which give me a terminal where i can excecute my MAKE commands

Comment: well, using that same connection, you can build up a connection between the CDT debugger and the remote gdb-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried remote debugging? I don't know how your server is set up, but perhaps try what [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) article is suggesting

Comment: you're not telling is in which way that was no use. Really, you're not giving any effort in describing what you've done and what did not work and what you really want to do.

Comment: i tried using remote debugging and also by using gdbserver...both the cases doesnt provide me to debug..the application just hangs .Incase of gdbserver application crashes

Comment: You need to be more descriptive, what was the target system, what error messages did you get? You said it was running on a server...did you check the server log? Those crashes should be logged somewhere. Also, if all fails, you can try the old-style line by line debugging (ie: logging your variables/calls into a file somewhere).

Comment: can someone tell me step by step procedure for remote debugging? ..thanks